# MySQL parameterized SELECT query with optional column filter

Tags: mysql, select

I have a requirement to build a versatile parameterized `SELECT` query which fetches data from a mysql table and optionally filters that data by values from a column in one fell swoop.

I know this can be achieved with mutltiple SELECTs, but it has to be just one statement.

The query either fetches all data if a NULL is passed or fetches filtered data if a value is passed in other than NULL.

One of the reasons for this requirement is we are externalizing our SQL strings.

I have managed to come up with this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` =  COALESCE(NULLIF(?,''),`column`);
```

I pass in a `NULL` when I need to fetch unfiltered data and it works smoothly, efficiently.

However, it never fetches data for which `**column**` is NULL.

How do I make it fetch columns with NULL data?

Comment: `WHERE column IS NULL`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (? IS NULL OR `column`=?);
```

It works with SQL Server and this query may have few syntactical errors but I just want to convey the approach which works in SQL Sever for this kind of problems.

What it does is, at first it checks for value of the input parameter, if it is `NULL` then it skips the filtering and if the parameter is not `NULL` then only it moves to the second part of the `OR` statement and does the filtering.

It differs from what you are currently trying is, it checks the parameter for `NULL` value and not the column.

Note: the problem with your query is- when you are passing `NULL`, the condition becomes `'column'=null` and thus it is not returning required rows. Rather we need to check columns for `NULL` value by `'column' IS NULL`.

Please let me know if I am missing something !